# jQuery .on click works only the first time for dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a widget that inserts dynamically into the web page using ajax and putting its own jquery in the header, everything works fine.

but when in that widget I paste some extra scripts to add some dynamically added elements waiting on user input, they do work fine, but the elements loaded with widget initially only get binded properly with the `.click()` event whereas the dynamic elements do work but only for the first time with some very weird behavior, like triggering the click many times (evident by a call I make on that click) and then not working again altogether, what could be the reason here, is the resident script of other websites messing with my script or is it something else ?

I'm using for all the elements:

```
$( 'body' ).on('click', '.page_link', someFunction);
```

Above didn't work so i tried this which work as expected with the elements pre-loaded in the widget but not so much with dynamically added ones:

```
$( '.page_link' ).click(someFunction);
$( 'body' ).on('click', '.page_link', someFunction);
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: can you create a fiddle example link so that we can and let you know the solution

Comment: Dynamic controls added to page once your page is loaded and available until your page is not getting refreshed. once your page is postback or reloaded again you've to re-attach the events. best way is you have to create one static parent element and have to assign your all dynamic controls to it. you have to also make sure to re-attach the events like parent.child.event = clickevent;

Comment: user3950705  did you checked comments and answers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573467/want-to-apply-events-to-the-tags-coming-to-the-js-widgets-through-database-using

Answer (score 2):

For dynamically loaded elements in jquery,You need to reapply the events(click)

As of jQuery 1.7 you can jQuery.fn.on:

```
$(parentSelector).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});
```

$(parentSelector) must be a non dyanamic element
For which you can either use `body` or a parent element where you appending dynamic element

Prior to jquery 1.7 you can use  was to use live():

```
$(selector).live( eventName, function(){} );
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use document global variable to bind click event. Try using following code :

```
$( document ).on('click', '.page_link', someFunction);
```

Comment: if it doesn't work from body... it's not gonna work from document.