# Want to apply events to the tags coming to the js widgets through database using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, widget, xss

> Here     **$('#example-widget-container').html("This data comes from another server: " + data);**    render the HTML data from a rest API.
>   I want to apply events on the html tags store in db using JQueries.
>   Please provide the help.

```js
(function() {

    // Localize jQuery variable
    var jQuery;

    /******** Load jQuery if not present *********/
    if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '1.4.2') {
        var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
        script_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        script_tag.setAttribute("src",
            "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
        if (script_tag.readyState) {
          script_tag.onreadystatechange = function () { // For old versions of IE
              if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {
                  scriptLoadHandler();
              }
          };
        } else {
          script_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
        }
        // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
        (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);
    } else {
        // The jQuery version on the window is the one we want to use
        jQuery = window.jQuery;
        main();
    }

    /******** Called once jQuery has loaded ******/
    function scriptLoadHandler() {
        // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
        // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
        jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
        // Call our main function
        main(); 
    }

    /******** Our main function ********/
    function main() { 
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
            /******* Load CSS *******/
            var css_link = $("<link>", { 
                rel: "stylesheet", 
                type: "text/css", 
                href: "style.css" 
            });
            css_link.appendTo('head');          

            /******* Load HTML *******/
            var jsonp_url = "http://xyz123/api/atmSearch";
            $.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(data) {
   console.log(data);
              $('#example-widget-container').html("This data comes from another server: " + data);
            });
        });
    }

    })(); // We call our anonymous function immediately
```

```html
  <body>
    <h1 id="header">Web Widget Tutorial</h1>
    <h2>Example 4 - Putting things together</h2>

    <div id="example-widget-container"></div>
  </body>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve your problem? Can you please show us some code for how you tried to apply the events?

Comment: To bind events to dynamically added content you need to use delegated event handlers. See the duplicate question for more information

Comment: You can check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571115/jquery-on-click-works-only-the-first-time-for-dynamic-elements/42571190#42571190). It will help.

Comment: Can you tell me where to apply the event part in the code